# Spring JPA N+1 select problem despite using LEFT JOIN FETCH for @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I think I'm doing everything as outlined [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/), for example, but I still get n+1 selects. No eager fetch type, specifying LEFT JOIN FETCH in @Query and it leaves me wondering why it doesn't work.

**User.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    // other fields & methods

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

**Role.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    // other fields & methods

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // tried both versions of these:

    @Query("FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles r WHERE u.username = :username")
    Optional<User> findUser(String username);

    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD,
            attributePaths = "roles")
    Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

**SELECTs for either query method**

```sql
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_2_0_, role2_.id as id1_1_1_, user0_.email as email2_2_0_, user0_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na4_2_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam5_2_0_, user0_.password_hash as password6_2_0_, user0_.username as username7_2_0_, role2_.role_name as role_nam2_1_1_, roles1_.user_id as user_id1_3_0__, roles1_.role_id as role_id2_3_0__ from users user0_ left outer join users_roles roles1_ on user0_.id=roles1_.user_id left outer join roles role2_ on roles1_.role_id=role2_.id where user0_.username=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [alice]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.email as email2_2_1_, user1_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam5_2_1_, user1_.password_hash as password6_2_1_, user1_.username as username7_2_1_ from users_roles users0_ inner join users user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id where users0_.role_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.email as email2_2_1_, user1_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam5_2_1_, user1_.password_hash as password6_2_1_, user1_.username as username7_2_1_ from users_roles users0_ inner join users user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id where users0_.role_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.email as email2_2_1_, user1_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam5_2_1_, user1_.password_hash as password6_2_1_, user1_.username as username7_2_1_ from users_roles users0_ inner join users user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id where users0_.role_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.email as email2_2_1_, user1_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam5_2_1_, user1_.password_hash as password6_2_1_, user1_.username as username7_2_1_ from users_roles users0_ inner join users user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id where users0_.role_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.email as email2_2_1_, user1_.email_verified as email_ve3_2_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam5_2_1_, user1_.password_hash as password6_2_1_, user1_.username as username7_2_1_ from users_roles users0_ inner join users user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id where users0_.role_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [6]
```

Comment: Looks like you've got one side of the Bidirectional relationship working fine, it is just now that you are fetching "roles", it is populating the Role.users collection using N queries. Why I can only guess as it should default to lazy and so not get built unless you trigger it. I don't know what options Hibernate has, but I prefer batch fetching over these relationship types (see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm ) as it can handle fetching role relationships in one query instead of N, without multiplying the data returned from your main q

Comment: @Chris you helped a lot pointing me to the right direction, previously I mainly checked what could be wrong with User, not realising that it is Role being filled with users during those N queries. As it turns out, **it was the hashCode and equals methods in Role that referred to the users set**. After removing users from there, it works as expected. Thanks. (Of course had there been a similar hashCode in User then I would have got StackOverFlowError when querying.)